# Cannot access member "text" for type "list[Unknown]"

Tags: python, disnake

```
@bot.command()
async def translate(ctx, lang, *, text):
    translator=Translator()
    translation=translator.translate(text, dest=lang)
    translated=translation.text
    embed=disnake.Embed(
    title="Перевод на различные языки",
    colour=000000
    )
    embed.add_field(
    name="Текст:",
    value=text,
    inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
    name="Язык:",
    value=lang,
    inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
    name="Перевод:",
    value=translated,
    inline=True
    )
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Ошибка жалуется на "text" в этой части кода:

```
translated=translation.text
```

ошибка жалуется на это:

```
Cannot access member "text" for type "list[Unknown]"
Member "text" is unknown
```

ошибка в строке 1092, как можно исправить эту ошибку на библиотеке disnake в версии библиотеки disnake 2.9.1 для дискорд бота